# JQuery doesn't locate DOM elements when using Durandal's compose

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal

I've recently ported my company's project to Durandal using Knockout and JQuery. Straight to the problem: I need to initialize JQuery UI's datepicker using two HTML inputs. JQuery, however, is unable to locate the inputs when I do this:

**view:**

```
<div data-bind="if: !CurrentUser()">
    <h1 data-bind="html: DisplayName"></h1>

    <div data-bind="compose: 'users/_UsersList.html'"></div>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: CurrentUser(), visible: CurrentUser()">
    <h1>User detail</h1>

    <div data-bind="compose: 'users/_UserDetail.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**viewmodel - SelectUser() function is called when a user is selected in the first div, then the second div and also users/_UserDetail.html is loaded:**

```
users.SelectUser = function (user) {
    users.CurrentUser(user);

    /* ... */

    $(function () {
        $("#datepickerFrom").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: "d. m. yy",
            timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
            defaultDate: null
        });

        $("#datepickerTo").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: "d. m. yy",
            timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss"
        });
    });
}
```

**The important part of _UserDetail.html**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Active from</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: ActiveFrom" id="datepickerFrom" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Active to</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: ActiveTo" id="datepickerTo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the two HTML inputs come as undefined. If I change the `div` with the `compose` binding to the actual users/_UserDetail.html content, it works just fine, but then the view quickly becomes a mess - the html file isn't exactly small. If someone could point me to the right direction, I would be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: You should create a custom binding handler and use that in your view. Also read the durandal doc about DOM manipulation: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM/

Comment: Are _you_ calling the code that loads the view? or is that handled by the framework?

Comment: Do you mean the `compose:` code? That is called by the framework, but it fires when `SelectUser()` is triggered - I call this function when I select a user from users/_UsersList.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this scenario you need a Knockout Binding Handler.

In some scenarios the binding handlers can have issues with the Composition lifecycle, if thats  the case and you are using Durandal 2 you can use the method `composition.addBindingHandler`. Otherwise just use `ko.bindingHandlers`.

You will need to create the bindings in the `shell.js` or `main.js` so they are available in all the application. Use the following code:

```
 var composition = require('durandal/composition');
 composition.addBindingHandler('datetimepicker', {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var activeTo =  valueAccessor();  //What do you want to do with this value?
                $(element).datetimepicker({
                   dateFormat: "d. m. yy",
                   timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
                   defaultDate: null   //Maybe use activeTo here?
                  });
            }
         });
```

And in your UI:

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="datetimepicker: ActiveTo" id="datepickerTo" />
```

**NOTE:**

This code might not work, but you should definitely use this approach to create this kind of controls and use Durandal's composition lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the problem is with this:

```
users.SelectUser = function (user) {
    servers.CurrentUser(user);

    /* ... */

    $(function () {
        $("#datepickerFrom").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: "d. m. yy",
            timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",
            defaultDate: null
        });

        $("#datepickerTo").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: "d. m. yy",
            timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss"
        });
    });
}
```

You have your jQuery datepicker init code inside a function. That means that it will only run when the `SelectUser` function gets called. Try moving that outside of any functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when SelectUser function is triggered, then _users/UserDetail.html and the two inputs get loaded - the two DOM elements don't exist until then.

Comment: Well, then using `$()` or `$(document).ready()` isn't really the right way to go, as since the view is getting loaded via AJAX the ready event has already fired.

Comment: What do you propose I should use instead of $()?

Comment: You need to figure out if you can hook into durandal's composition mechanism. Most frameworks expose an event that gets fired when the content gets loaded/added to the DOM. _That's_ where you want to set up your datepickers.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to read through their docs once again, now that I know what I need to look for. :) Thanks.