# Override Durandal's display:none behavior in Compose binding

Tags: durandal

I am using Durandal's compose binding and I am currently running into an issue caused by the fact that Durandal's compose binding sets the injected view's root element to display:none until the activate's promise is resolved.

The issue is that the injected view has a custom binding that needs to know the initial dimensions of its bound element, but because its parent is display:none the element will always have a width/height of 0 pixels.

The solution is to use visibility:hidden instead of display:none during composition, but I can't find a way to override that behavior using the compose binding. Is there a way to specify this in the binding syntax? If not, would it be possible to create a custom transition to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually not a really good idea to override behavior of Compose module.

In your case it would be better if you will **execute your binding after your View is composed**.

For this you need to add your binding to **composition bindings** after app.start() in main.js:

```
composition.addBindingHandler('yourBindingName');
```

In this case your **binding will be called in time when root element is already visible** and after view composition.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. For those that are interested, an actual example of where and how to register a custom binding using addBindingHander can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701228/jquery-doesnt-locate-dom-elements-when-using-durandals-compose

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to override this behavior in the `compose` binding.  However, I do think you could accomplish this behavior using a custom binding or transition.

For the transition, try modifying the transition so that it sets the view's `visibility` and `display` attributes as desired.

The other idea is to use a custom binding that only implements the `init` function.  In this function, you could set the view's attributes.

Now this may work, but I think for either case, you'll probably also have to clear the visibility attribute once you're ready to show it.  You could do this from the `attached` view model function.

---

Another, maybe cleaner, alternative is to consider moving the computation logic to the `attached` view model function, because at this time, durandal has loaded and displayed the view.  If this is suitable, you wouldn't have to mess with the `visibility` attribute at all.